# Add picture in header to a .docx using novacode DocX

Tags: c#, .net, docx

```
Header header_default = doc.Headers.first;
Paragraph p1 = header_default.InsertParagraph();
```

I've tried to add a picture in my header in a word file. I tried it with:

```
p1.AppendPicture(picture);
```

And also with a table:

```
Table t1 = header_default.InsertTable(10,2);
t1.Pictures.Add(picture);
```

Well the big problem is that the code never run to this place it's always crashing by inserting a paragraph to the header:

```
Paragraph p1 = header_default.InsertParagraph();
```

or

```
Table t1 = header_default.InsertTable(10,2);
```

Error: `System.NullReferenceException`

I'm new in .net and docx library hope someone can help me with the prblem

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/ff194465.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how I do it, notice I use Doc.Headers.odd rather than first

```
        Doc.AddHeaders();
        var headerDefault = Doc.Headers.odd;
        var headlineFormat = GetTopHeadlineFormat();
        var logo = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(AppSettings.MulalleyLogoSmall);
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            logo.Save(ms, logo.RawFormat);
            ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            var img = Doc.AddImage(ms);
            var pic1 = img.CreatePicture();
            var p = headerDefault.InsertParagraph();
            p.InsertPicture(pic1);
            p.InsertParagraphBeforeSelf(Doc.InsertParagraph());
        }
```